How to create a nested Loop in Powershell script
I have the following powershell script that I am using to download files via RestAPI.  I want to loop through all the URLS that I place in the $urlCollection variable and download the files.  These URLS are split out into single values using a split function.  The url loop works, and the script iterates through the $urlCollection, but I need it to also iterate through the $fileCollection and make the filename dynamic as well.
For example
foreach ($url in $urlList) {

 Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get -OutFile $file

}

param (
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $false)]
    [object] $WebHookData
)
# Get all parameters from body 
# (passed from Data Factory Web Activity)
$Parameters = (ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $WebhookData.RequestBody)
# Save Parameters for readability
# Check for ADF parameter. Not used when testing interactively
If ($Parameters.callBackUri)
{
    $callBackUri = $Parameters.callBackUri
}
# Demo parameter
$ParmMsg =  $Parameters.ParmMsg
# Main Script
Write-Output $ParmMsg
 
 
# If called from a webhook, use callBackUri to notify task is complete
If ($callBackUri)
{
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $callBackUri -Method Post
}

# set date for dynamic date field
#$date = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d"
$date = "2024-04-04"
$user = "username"
$pass = "password"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$pass)))
$option = [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries
$urlCollection = "https://url1/rest/ofscCore/v1/folders/dailyExtract/folders/" + $date + "/files/file1.xml","https://url2/rest/ofscCore/v1/folders/dailyExtract/folders/" + $date + "/files/file2.xml"
$separator = ","
$urlList = $urlCollection.Split($separator, $option)
$fileCollection = "file1.xml","file2.xml"
$fileList = $fileCollection.Split($separator, $option)




foreach ($url in $urlList) {

 Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get -OutFile $file

}

The $file should be one of the files in the $fileCollection variable, so that the url is dynamic and the filename is dynamic as well.  I am thinking this is going to require a nested loop, but not sure how to do that.

could you provide and example of the intended result? You need to get all the files in $FileCollection for each of the URLs in $UrlList?

If you are only looking for a nested loop, it's as simple as this:
foreach ($url in $urlList) {
   foreach ($file in $fileList) {
      Write-Host "URL: $url, FILE: $file"
    }
}

But based on the code you posted you might not  need this.  Your URLs are the same except for the filename, so perhaps this will work:
foreach ($file in $fileList) {
  $url = "https://url2/rest/ofscCore/v1/folders/dailyExtract/folders/$date/files/$file"
  Write-Host "URL: $url"
}


the URLs are actually different: url1 and url2
